Regex text group but fails with empty values
I have a (Python) regex string that extracts the ID after the name and up to the end of the line, using the following, which also caters for spaces or no spaces before/after the colon:
ID\s?:\s?(.\*)\r\*\n

https://regex101.com/r/qvMOdC/1
ID: an id
Rule name: abc
Severity: Medium

I want to cater for no ID present, but the above only works when there is a space after the colon, i.e. ID:  works fine but when I do ID:, i.e. there is no space after the colon just a new line it gives me Rule name: abc as the ID.
How to fix? Thanks.

This issue is happening due to use of \s? after matching :. Just keep in mind that \s matches any whitespace including line break. So when there is no space after : it matches \n that is right after :.
You may use this regex to fix this issue:
^ID[ \t]*:[ \t]*(.*)\r?\n

Updated RegEx Demo
Here [ \t]* matches zero or more of a space or tab characters.
